# cakephp4 test title length

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, integration-testing

I need to test the length of page title in integration tests.
I have a solution, but I'd like to know if there is a better one.

My solution is :

```
    $response = $this->get('/faqs/index');
    $this->assertResponseOk();

    $body=$this->_getBodyAsString();
    preg_match('@<title>(.*)</title>@i',$body,$matches);
    $this->assertTrue(strlen($matches[1])>10);
```

Comment: I mean... my question would be why you need to assert the length as opposed to say the content?

Comment: I guess it's the same problem ? what is the best way to get the title of the page ?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using regex for parsing markup, better use an Xpath query:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($body);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("//title");
$title = $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

With this as a simple approach, you can get the title and then assert the length.